# comparing two time values in an if statement

Tags: javascript

i need to compare two values and do stuff with the result of the comaprison depending on if the times are more than 1 hour apart.

So for example

```
Time1 = 13:07:01    
Now = 13:26:47
```

what i need to do is in an if statement compare to see if Now is an hour ahead of Time one for example

```
If( Comparison){
  1 hour has passed
}else{
  1 hour has not passes 
}
```

What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: I assume this should wrap around at midnight? i.e. 23:59 should be "within an hour" of 00:01?

Comment: Is 00:01:00 an hour after 23:01:00? If so, is it ten hours after 14:01:00, or fourteen hours earlier?

Comment: `(Time1 - Now) / 1000 / 60 / 60` - time difference in hours for simple Date

Comment: Is there any chance you can include the date? It would make your life way easier.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Answer (score 2):

Use `Date()` - [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

```
if (Date.now() > new Date(oldDate) + 1000 * 60 * 60) {
    console.log('1 hour has passed');
} else {
    console.log('1 hour has not passed');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    <script>
        function checkForOneHr(){
              var start = '5:30';
              var end = '6:50';
              s = start.split(':');
              e = end.split(':');
              min = e[1]-s[1];
              hour_carry = 0;
              if(min < 0){
                  min += 60;
                  hour_carry += 1;
              }
              hour = e[0]-s[0]-hour_carry;
              if(hour >= 1)
               return true;
              else
               return false;
        } 

       if( checkForOneHr()){
           alert('1 hour has passed');
        }else{
          alert(' hour has not passes ');
         }


   </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If they are Date objects

```
var now = new Date();
var diff = now.getTime() - time1.getTime();
if(diff >= 1000*60*60) {
    console.log('an hour has passed');
} else {
    console.log('an hour has not passed');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

First of All , Convert Both the times to string format using,

strtotime().

See any PHP manual.

Take out the difference of them.

The result will be difference in seconds.

Divide the difference by 3600.

If it is greater then 1, do your 'Code to do".

eg. 
$current_time = date('T-m-d H:I:S');
$time_now = strtotime($current_time);

Comment: The question is tagged javascript not php.

Comment: I did not Notice that, But Server side scripting is always more reliable then Client Side.

Still, Your above answer is  correct only.